# When unramified maps are smooth coverings?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $Y$ be a projective manifold that is also a compact complex manifold. Assume that there is a finite unramified covering $p : \widetilde Y \to Y$. Is it possible to assume that $p$ is a smooth covering map with sheets consisting of a finite number of points?

I must say that I am no algebraic geometer, but as far as I understand, the hypothesis of ''unramified covering map'' on Riemann surfaces implies the result provided if the map $p$ is holomorphic and not constant. So, if $p$ in this case happens to be a topological covering map, it is possible to consider a unique smooth structure on $\widetilde Y$ such that $p$ is a smooth covering map. Is this right?

Concerning the hypothesis of $p$ being finite, I see that this is a very algebraic characterization, can this imply what I asked about the sheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true without assuming something extra of the map $\widetilde{Y}\to Y$. Consider $\Bbb P^1\sqcup \Bbb P^0 \to \Bbb P^1$ where the map from $\Bbb P^1$ is the identity and the map from $\Bbb P^0$ is the inclusion of some (closed) point. This satisfies all of your stated assumptions, but is not a covering map.

The missing ingredient is flatness: once you have that, you have an etale morphism. Combining that with your assumption it's surjective and finite, such a morphism is the algebro-geometric interpretation of a finite-sheeted covering map from topology, and everything you ask for is true.

As far as the smooth structure stuff goes, I think there are problems with what you're trying to do. Being able to define holomorphicity of $p$ already gives a smooth structure on $\widetilde{Y}$, and objects in algebraic geometry are generally considered in such a way that the equivalent of a smooth structure is intrinsic to the data of the object.

Comment: thank you very much! Can you explain a little about the "flatness assumption"?

Comment: In our situation, it's primary benefit is that it forces our map to be open - the problem with the conditions you originally wrote is that you could always disjoint-union in a closed immersion from some smaller-dimensional variety, which breaks the covering map bit. But this can't happen if our map is open. If you're looking for a more in-depth explanation of what flatness "really is", I'd suggest [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6789/why-are-flat-morphisms-flat/) plus [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/75317/flatness-in-complex-analytic-geometry).